# Coefficient value of covariate in Cox PH model is too big

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am trying to develop Cox PH model with time-varying covariates in R. I use `coxph` function from `survival` package. There was not any trouble during estimation process, though coefficient value of one covariates is too large, in particular, 2.5e+32.

[image]

I can't guess what is reason of this problem and how to tackle it. This variable is nonstationary and proportional assumption is violated. Does either of this facts may cause such a big value of coefficient?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

More information could help framing your problem.

Anyway, I doubt non-proportionality is to blame. It would imply that you have some outliers heavily biasing your coefficient beyond reasonable expectations. You could give this a quick look by plotting the output of `cox.zph`.

Another possible explanation is that this rather depends on the unit of measure you used to define your covariate. Can the magnitude of the coefficient be meaningfully interpreted? If so, you could simply re-scale/standardise/log-transform that covariate to obtain a 'more manageable' coefficient (if this is theoretically appropriate).

This could also be due to the so called 'complete separation', which has been discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385865/extremely-huge-hazard-ratios-from-cox-regression) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61553/explaining-an-extremely-large-coefficient-in-a-rare-events-logistic-regression).